# Div Diamond with straight background image

Tags: css

I have a couple divs, I want to rotate them to look like diamonds, but I don't want their background images to rotate, how can i achieve this? This is my code right now

```
<div id="diamonds">

<div class="diamond-big diamond-tiesto"><img src="<?php echo $images_url; ?>dj-1-overlay.png" /></div>

</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#diamonds div {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg); 
float:left;
}

.diamond-tiesto {background-image:url('images/dj-1.jpg'); background-size:cover; width:212px; height:212px; margin-left:160px; margin-right:120px;}
.diamond-tiesto img {margin-top:80px; margin-left:-20px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg); 
}
```

Basically I am trying to achieve this http://mqchen.github.io/jquery.diamonds.js/ without the jquery, anyone have any suggestions

Heres a fiddle just incase:

http://jsfiddle.net/7qj8h/1/

Comment: can you just rotate that photo if you are using only that one :)

Comment: updated the code, I want to rotate the div, but have its background image stay straight

Answer (score 1):

You could use the techniques described in [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/) and apply the transformation to a background image pseudo-element.

Demo/Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7qj8h/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="diamonds">
    <div class="diamond-big diamond-tiesto">
        <img src="http://solarismusicfestival.com/new/wp-content/themes/default-blank/images/dj-1-overlay.png" />
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.diamond-big
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    /* rotate diamond */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.label {
    /* counter rotate label */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    /* position label */
    margin-top:80px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
.diamond-big:before
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;

    /* counter rotate bg */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* set bg for different DJs */
.diamond-tiesto:before {
        background: url(http://solarismusicfestival.com/new/wp-content/themes/default-blank/images/dj-1.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the `.diamond` to rotate 45 degrees
2. Set the background on a `.diamond-inner` child div, and rotate it back -45 degrees to counter the parent's transformation.
3. Set `overflow: hidden;` on the `.diamond` div to clip the edges.
4. Adjust the positioning on the inner diamond and image.

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/7qj8h/3/

The CSS:

```
#diamonds > div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.diamond-tiesto {
    width:212px;
    height:212px;
}

 .diamond-tiesto .diamond-inner {
    background-image: url("http://solarismusicfestival.com/new/wp-content/themes/default-blank/images/dj-1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 305px;
    left: 2px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -49px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 305px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.diamond-tiesto img {
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 123px;
}
```